# Combine results of joins on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, left-join

I have 3 tables

```
items
  tag_id
  mark_id

tags_users
  tag_id
  user_id

marks_users
  mark_id
  user_id
```

Is there a way to select unique `items` for specific `user_id` without `UNION` and nested selects?

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
INNER JOIN tags_users ON tags_users.tag_id = items.tag_id
AND  tags_users.user_id = 5

UNION

SELECT items.*
FROM items
INNER JOIN marks_users ON marks_users.mark_id = items.mark_id
AND marks_users.user_id = 5
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to accomplish. Could you post an example desired result-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Linked by `(tag_id, mark_id)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
FROM   tags_users  tu  
JOIN   marks_users mu USING (user_id)
JOIN   items       i  USING (tag_id, mark_id)
WHERE  tu.user_id = 5;
```

The `DISTINCT` should not be necessary, if you have defined multi-column primary or unique keys on the columns.

#### Linked by `tag_id` *or* `mark_id`

@Gordon's answer is perfectly valid. But it will perform *terribly*.
This will be much faster:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   items i  
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   tags_users  tu
    WHERE  tu.tag_id = i.tag_id
    AND    tu.user_id = 5
    )
OR     EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   marks_users mu 
    WHERE  mu.mark_id = i.mark_id
    AND    mu.user_id = 5
    );
```

Assumes that entries in `items` itself are UNIQUE on `(tag_id, mark_id)`.

### Why is this *much* faster?

If you `JOIN` to two unrelated tables (like in @Gordon's answer), you effectively form a **cross join**, which are known for rapidly degrading performance with growing number of rows. O(N²). Say, you have:

- 100 users, 100 tags and 100 marks.
- Every combination exists (simple hypothetical setup, real life data will be less balanced).
- Results in 10,000 rows in each of the tables.

This will happen in @Gordon's query:

1. JOIN rows of `items` to `tags_users`. Each item is joined to 100 rows, resulting in
   10,000 x 100 = 1,000,000 rows. (!)
2. JOIN that to `marks_users`. Each row is joined to 100 marks, resulting in
   100,000,000 rows. (!!)
3. The `WHERE` clause is applied and the many duplicates are collapsed by `DISTINCT`, resulting in 10,000 rows.

Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html). The difference will be obvious even with small numbers and staggering with growing numbers.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/81dc3/4)

### Benchmarks

I ran some quick tests with this setup on my machine (pg 9.1):

#### Gordon's query

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN tags_users tu on i.tag_id = tu.tag_id
LEFT   JOIN marks_users mu on i.mark_id = mu.mark_id
WHERE  5 IN (tu.user_id, mu.user_id);
```

Total runtime: **38229.860 ms**

#### Sanitized version

Pulling the condition on `user_id` into the `JOIN` clause cuts down on the combinations radically, but it is still a **(much tinier) cross join**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN tags_users tu on i.tag_id = tu.tag_id AND tu.user_id = 5
LEFT   JOIN marks_users mu on i.mark_id = mu.mark_id AND mu.user_id = 5
WHERE  tu.user_id = 5 OR mu.user_id = 5;
```

Total runtime: **110.450 ms**

#### With EXISTS semi-joins

(see query above)
With this query, every row is checked once if it qualifies. You don't need a `DISTINCT`, because rows are not duplicated to begin with.

Total runtime: **26.569 ms**

#### UNION

For completeness, the variant with `UNION`. Use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL` to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   items i 
JOIN   tags_users  tu ON i.tag_id = tu.tag_id AND tu.user_id = 5
UNION
SELECT i.*
FROM   items i 
JOIN   marks_users mu ON i.mark_id = mu.mark_id AND mu.user_id = 5;
```

Total runtime: **178.901 ms**

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: No. This assumes that both are needed.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: The requirement should have gone into your question. I added a variant for either-or.

Comment: Items itself are not UNIQUE on (tag_id, mark_id) in my case, so i have already used cross joins with constraints on user_id in joins. And later i will test how inner joins with union perform.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: I added a variant with `UNION` for completeness.

Comment: Thanks again. Didn't know about sqlfiddle, very nice tool.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the specific question was about syntax and not performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Sure looks like retaliation. The proper way would be to remove or improve your answer, which would allow me to remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do this by joining the tables together and looking at the user ids in the tags and marks tables.  You have to be careful about getting duplicates.

The following is an example of how to do this:

```
select distinct i.tag_id, i.user_id
from items i left outer join
     tags_users tu
     on i.tag_id = tu.tag_id left outer join
     marks_users mu
     on i.mark_id = mu.mark_id
where 5 in (tu.user_id, mu.user_id)
```

Or you can change the where clause to:

```
where tu.user_id = 5 or mu.user_id = 5
```

I want to emphasize that this answer addresses the original question, which asked about a particular way to formulate a query (without using joins or subqueries).  This query may not be efficient; however, it answers the original question.  I have no idea why the original question placed these constraints on the answer, but I chose not to address the limitations, only the question that was asked.  I definitely use unions and subqueries; in fact, I'm sometimes criticized for over-using the latter.

In some databases, this would be efficiently compiled; others (such as postgres) seem to do a poorer job. However, the original question did not specify the size of the data or give any hint about the need for performance.

Comment: this query returns nothing in my case)

Comment: If the lookup tables (tags and marks) are not populated for all values in items, then you need to use a left outer join.

Comment: it is better but `where 5 in (tu.user_id, mu.user_id)` doesn't work because `tu` and `mu` is not in `from` clause, and if i add them there pg reports error `specified more than once'

Comment: and last question, performance wise that is better union or outer joins?

Comment: Joins are typically better than unions.  For instance, they can make use of indexes and the results generally have better statistics on them (compared to the results of a union/union all).

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: `UNION` does something different entirely than an `OUTER JOIN`.  That's comparing apples and oranges. Individual `SELECTs` of a `UNION` can use indexes just as well, btw.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter . . . there are cases where either UNION or JOIN can be used for a query, so the question is a fair question.  Whether *union all* uses an index would depend on the database.  For a union, I would be surprised if any preserved the underlying index structure because of the elimination of duplicates.  I could be wrong, but it would surprise me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You are thinking of indexes being used for ORDER BY, and you are probably right there. The far more common benefit from indexes is in looking up rows according to conditions. Also, queries that can equally well use UNION or JOIN are very rare - because they are very different.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: After some consideration I am going do downvote this answer. **Do not use this query**! It is a black hole for performance. It may work acceptably with few rows, but will practically stall your server when the numbers grow. I provided the rationale in my answer.

Comment: The question wasn't about performance . . . it was about doing the work "without union and nested selects".

Comment: This query can stall a server in a sneaky way and is **very** bad advice in any case.

Comment: The added disclaimer should do.